# gparted error message

Tags: gparted, dd

Edit: I have just noticed that even after reformating the usb stick that in gparted there is a red circle with an exclamation mark and clicking on it brings up the warning.

> plain floppy: device "/dev/sda" busy (Resource temporarily
>   unavailable): Cannot initialize '::' mlabel: Cannot initialize drive

I reformatted the usb stick to FAT 32 via both gparted and Nautilus. How can I get rid of this message.

Comment: It isn't clear from your description so I'm asking: You are checking it from another system, correct? Not from the live session booted from the same drive, correct? Anyway, I think you should have imaged the whole drive, i.e., `sda` instead of `sda1`.

Comment: I am running  18.10 on my laptop running from the hard drive. I plugged in a USB stick, checked where it was mounted (/dev/sda) and then copied the first partition using the command shown above. I then unmounted it and plugged in the second usb stick, checked where it was mounted and copied the image onto it via the second command above. I didn't copy the whole disk originally because when I did that earlier I couldn't copx the omage onto the second usb stick because there wasn't enough space on the second usb stick even though they are both 16GB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer after a lot of trial and error. First of all I reformatted the usb stick with FAT32. In gparted the red warning circle was still there. I then made a new partition table using `Device-Create partition`, selecting `MS-DOS` and then clicking the green tick. I then selected `Partition-New` and then the green tick and then I had a new FAT32 partition without any warning.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like incorrect flash partitioning.

the easy fix (usually) is dd...

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/[usb_here]

that will wipe it finding the first and last sectors.

then format it normally